# On computations related with $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}\sum_{\rho}\frac{(e^x)^\rho}{\rho}=0$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, absolute-convergence, chebyshev-function

**When I've reproduced the shape of the function** $\sigma(x)$ of **Apostol's section 4.10**, a view of the page 98 is avaible as a Google Book (Apostol, Introduction to Analytic Number Theory, Springer 1976), **in the LHS of the explicit formula** (I say the formula in first paragraph of [page 343](http://www.ams.org/notices/200303/fea-conrey-web.pdf), **Conrey**, The Riemann Hypothesis from **Notices of the AMS**) **then the Prime Number Theorem implies** $$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}\sum_{\rho}\frac{(e^x)^\rho}{\rho}=0,$$ where the series is over the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta function, and the nature/problems of such sum and series is explained in the subsequent paragraph of previous article. I believe that previous limit makes sense by my computations, but I don't know what is its full meaning, by the nature of such series.

> **Question 1.** Is right previous limit? Is right the substitution that I've computed $x\leftarrow e^x$?  Can you explain what is the meaning of such series and limit? It is, how we can understand previous limit? **Thanks in advance.**

Also I am interesting in the following, but if it is lot of work (you are welcome to answer it, if you want or well) provide us hints about the next

> **Question 2.** Without the **Prime Number Theorem** what computations and statements can you prove about 
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}\sum_{\rho}\frac{(e^x)^\rho}{\rho}$$
>   when the series is interpreted as same as the cited paragraph? I say, that you can take the complex modulus, real and imaginary parts, get bounds, use the definition of limit...to obtain easy claims that I can learn without a heavy tool likes the Prime Number Theorem. **Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\psi\left(x\right)=\sum_{p^{m}\leq x}\log\left(p\right)
 $$ where $x
 $ is not a prime power. From the [Perron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula): we have $$\psi\left(x\right)=\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\sum_{p^{m}\leq x}\frac{\log\left(p\right)}{p^{ms}}\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds
 $$ $$=-\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}\left(s\right)\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds$$ with $\textrm{Re}\left(s\right)>1
 $. Now if we move the contour to the left we have, from the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), that $$\psi\left(x\right)=x-\sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}-\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}\left(0\right)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)
 $$ where the first term follows from the pole of Zeta at $s=1
 $, the series from the non trivial zeros, $\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}\left(0\right)
 $ from the pole at $s=0
 $ and $\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)
 $ from the trivial zeros. This is essentially how we get the explicit formula. Note that the PNT is equivalent to $$\psi\left(x\right)\sim x
 $$ then $$x^{-1}\left|\sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}\right|\rightarrow0.
 $$ Note that the series converges conditionally but not absolutely, so there is no “easy claims”.

Comment: Very thanks much, tomorrow at the morning I will and study your answer. I accept your words that there is no easy claims for the limit, I understand it.

Comment: @user243301 Actually I don't know if there are "easy claims" (I interpret it as easy manipulations of the series for proving convergence) but since there is no absolutely convergence I bet on the no. Note that if you take the sum considering each zeros with is conjugate then you have the absolutely convergence.

Comment: My main problem, thus I understand that your answer 
perfectly satisfactory, was is the substitution $e^x$ provide us some advantage in the knowledge, but now I understand that the limit is only the Prime Number THeorem. I thought in improve, in meaning, my question(s) (deleting some of my questions), but still I don't decide it . Thanks for your patience and attention.

Comment: @user243301 What I wrote holds for every positive (not prime power) $x$. So if we take $x=e^{y}$ the claim is the same.

Comment: Ok your last comment, with respect your previous question, as I've said in previous comments, my problem is that I am asking in this site by statements that I don't know very well. In previous  myself **Question**, with easy claims about the limit, **I ask if you or other user can deduce something about the limit** $$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}\sum_{\rho}\frac{(e^x)^\rho}{\rho}$$ without great theorems, this is **only with tools from a** $1^{st}$ **course in analysis.**  Very thanks much.

Comment: @ Marco :  before applying the residue theorem you'll need to prove that the density of zeros in the critical strip is low enough such that $\displaystyle \int_{\sigma+iT_k}^{-\infty+iT_k} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{s \zeta(s)} x^s ds \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ where $T_k = Im(\frac{\textstyle \rho_k + \rho_{k+1}}{2})$